# Excel pivot table hides complete row when blank values or labels are filtered

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a nested pivot table as shown in picture.
If I filter out the (blank), then my helloworld.cpp also gets hidden. How do I hide / do not show (blank) but keep the helloworld.cpp in the nested pivot table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQkVD.png)

Comment: Select Row Labels ,, then from the list appears, click the box below Select field and select the field you need to hide its blank rows, and uncheck it !!